# How can I quit VLC from Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, vlc-media-player

Anybody knows how to quit VLC app (VLC v3.0.10) from Mac Terminal? already tried "killall VLC" and "vlc://quit" to no avail. If I quit the already open instance from MacOS GUI, a new instance start automatically!

Comment: The regular command is "killall", followed by either the name of the application, or its PID (Process ID). You can add a "sudo" in front of "killall" if need be, but "killall vlc" should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry Didier, but  "killall VLC" or "killall /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC" doesn't do the trick on Mac Terminal. Man says "vlc://quit", but doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

Use the top command to find the PID of VLC and then use the kill command.
Example PID is 10443, use "kill 10443".

You can also use Activity Monitor in the Utility folder if you cannot find the PID that way(which also allows you to kill processes) or "ps aux" in the terminal to show all processes.

Comment: UserZer0, any special syntax to use? Tried "killall 10443" "killall PID10443" "killall PID 10443" without success.

Comment: kill 10443 , killall is for names.

Comment: Also if VLC continues to relaunch after being killed, check your keyboard, you may have media keys that are stuck.

Comment: Add a "sudo" in front of your command then enter your admin password should be enough. If VLC starts again on its own after being killed, then your problem is elsewhere. Have you tried to reset VLC preferences, either from the GUI (Menu > Preferences > Reset All) or by navigating to your home folder, under Library/Preferences, and delete the org.videolan.vlc.plist file AFTER closing VLC. Go into Recovery Mode if you have to, you'll have a free rein on things. Is your VLC up-to-date? Could be that it's trying to update to the latest version, without success.

Comment: Didier, strange VLC (or Terminal) reaction here. Kill process ID don't work either. Terminal is only moving prompt one line below, like when processing something but I can't see anything being processed. Quitting VLC from the GUI makes Terminal answers all the preceding command lines with error messages like "kill: <processID>: command not found" and "kill: <processID>: no such process" that is normal as I just quit from the GUI. But why no answer from terminal while VLC is still running????

Comment: UserZer0, thanks, but no such keyboard problem here

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
killall VLC
```

Applikation name "VLC" (VideoLan client) needs to be uppercase, like its name in installation:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
```